Cannot run .NET 8 lambda in Rider
We're setting up a new lambdas solution using the Annotations framework and targeting .NET 8.
When setting up our Run/Debug Configurations in Rider, we're getting an error message at the bottom of the configuration window that says only Error: The runtime 'dotnet8' is unsupported.
The AWS toolkit for rider seems to insist that .NET 8 is, in fact, supported.
Some extra bits of context: we have gotten this to work by rolling back to .NET 6 just to prove our configuration works, but cannot target .NET 6 long-term. We are also able to get this to work through the same cli with .NET 8, but then we don't get all of the debugging tools we desperately need, and that the rest of the team are more familiar with.
Happy to provide any other details that might be required. Really just trying to determine if anyone else has run into this issue and found a way to solve it.

This is a known AWS plugin issue. The only workaround at the moment is to target .NET 6 until this issue is resolved.

Not sure how I wasn't able to find this when looking through their issues, but that seems to be an open and shut case. Thank you!
